# AngularJS - input for name or email, How to implement?

Tags: angularjs, validation

How to to implement validation for input:

That if there is no `@` so it's a name. and should be a minimum of 3 characters.

And if there have `@` - so it's a Email. and he must to be a valid Email

I'm trying to think of a way how to do it and I can not find

I want to show the errors based on

i.e:
If no `@` - error would be only for a minimum characters

And if there `@` - Error will be for a valid email

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="email"
   ng-model="string"
   [name="string"]
   [required="string"]
   [ng-required="string"]
   [ng-minlength="number"]
   [ng-maxlength="number"]
   [pattern="string"]
   [ng-pattern="string"]
   [ng-change="string"]>

 <input name="email" type="email" ng-model="obj.email" ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is excellent [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) + examples are provided on AngularJs official site.

Check input [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) and customize them according to your need:

```
<input
  ng-model="string"
  [name="string"]
  [required="string"]
  [ng-required="boolean"]
  [ng-minlength="number"]
  [ng-maxlength="number"]
  [ng-pattern="string"]
  [ng-change="string"]
  [ng-trim="boolean"]>
...
</input>
```

For `input[email]`

```
<input type="email"
       ng-model="string"
       [name="string"]
       [required="string"]
       [ng-required="string"]
       [ng-minlength="number"]
       [ng-maxlength="number"]
       [pattern="string"]
       [ng-pattern="string"]
       [ng-change="string"]>
```